# Loss going to NaN after few iterations

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

In my model, the input is a graph data in the form of *edge-index* and the node *features*. After a few iterations of training on graph data, loss (**EDIT**: which is a combination of MSELoss function and a negative loss function i.e., **L1** + *(***-L2**)) becomes NaN. Both **L1** and **-L2** become NaN after around 40 iterations.

Learning rate = 0.00001. I also checked for invalid input data also, but found none.

```py
from torch.nn.parameter import Parameter
from torch.nn.modules.module import Module
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
import networkx as nx
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
from torch_geometric.data import Data

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nin, nhid1, nout, inp_l, hid_l, out_l=1):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.g1 = GCNConv(in_channels= nin, out_channels= nhid1)
        self.g2 = GCNConv(in_channels= nhid1, out_channels= nout)
        self.dropout = 0.5
        self.lay1 = nn.Linear(inp_l ,hid_l)
        self.lay2 = nn.Linear(hid_l ,out_l)

    def forward(self, x, adj):
        x = F.relu(self.g1(x, adj))
        x = F.dropout(x, self.dropout, training=self.training)
        x = self.g2(x, adj)
        
        x = self.lay1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.lay2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        
        return x
```

The inputs to the model:

**x** (Tensor , optional ) – Node feature matrix with shape [num_nodes, num_node_features].

**edge_index** (LongTensor , optional ) – Graph connectivity in COO format with shape [2, num_edges]

Here num_nodes=1000 ; num_node_features=1 ; num_edges = 5000

[GCNConv](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#torch_geometric.nn.conv.GCNConv) is a graph embedder returns a [num_nodes, dim] matrix. It takes in the edge-list and the features to return a matrix.

**EDIT 2: Added how the loss is calculated**

```py
def train_model(epoch):
    model= Model(nin = 1, nhid1=128, nout=128, inp_l=128, hid_l=64, out_l=1).to(device)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00001)

    model.train()
    t = time.time()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    Y = model(features, adjacency_list)

    Y1 = func(Y) #Y1 values are calculated from Y by passing through a function func to obtain a same sized vector as Y

    loss1 = ((Y1-Y)**2).mean()  #MSE Loss function
    
    loss2 = -Y.abs().mean() # This loss is implemented to prevent Y values going to 0. Notice the "-" sign
    
    loss_train = loss1 + loss2
    loss_train.backward(retain_graph=True)
    nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.5)

    optimizer.step()
    
    if epoch%20==0:
        print("MSE loss = ",loss1,"\t","Mean Loss = ",loss2)
        print('Epoch: {:04d}'.format(epoch+1),
                  'loss_train: {:.4f}'.format(loss_train.item()),
                  'time: {:.4f}s'.format(time.time() - t))
        print("\n\n")

    return Y
```

Comment: As an initial guess, there might an underflow happening when you compute the second power of Y1-Y. Could you instead try `loss1 = (Y1-Y).mean()` ? Does it become NaN in that case as well? and if yes, does it take maybe more epoch to get the NaN ?

Comment: @berkayberabi Yes, it becomes NaN in that case as well. No, it takes almost the same no. of epochs. I don't think the MSELoss is the issue though, because when I implemented the same code without using PyTorch Geometric, but for adjacency matrix, there's no NaN Loss issue.